# Converting a table into a formula / equation

Tags: mathematics, rpg

I need help to figure out the formula / equation or at least the growth rate based on this table. All I can see is that the base stat is 12 as STAT2 = 2 x base and STAT3 = 5 x base.

[image]

Comment: Questions: Do you want the literal formula or are you just trying to fill in the missing numbers?

Answer (score 5):

I tried to figure this out by creating an MS Excel spreadsheet and experimenting with different formulas until I found one which works.

A formula which approximates the values in that table very closely seems to be `a + b * (level / 10)²`  with the following values for a and b:

```
        a    b
STAT1  12   10
STAT2  24   20
STAT3  60   50
```

It is not an *exact* fit. the results for level 100 are 1012, 2024 and 5060 respectively. But this is likely close enough for your purpose.

If the table comes from a different game and you want to clone it, then you shouldn't try to copy them too closely anyway in order to avoid copyright problems.

If this is a table from your own game and you are trying to reverse-engineer it because the knowledge how to create it was lost, then a 0.06% deviation is unlikely to turn your game balance upside down. (but on the other hand, I know absolutely nothing about your game mechanics, so I can't be *completely* certain about that)

Answer (score 0):

The best fit I found was via cubic fit (least squares). the last two stats were almost spot on entirely, and the first one was only about 99.98% fit or something which yielded the following results:

```
// let x represent the level, and y represent the corresponding stat's output

// Stat1: y = -3.99983×10^-6 x^3 + 0.100512 x^2 - 0.00664512 x + 11.5483
// Stat2: y = -1.57334×10^-8 x^3 + 0.200103 x^2 + 0.00463321 x + 23.5259
// Stat3: y =  0.0000107514 x^3 + 0.498893 x^2 + 0.0373237 x + 59.5811
```

if you round the resulting y quantity to its nearest integer, you will find the results extremely accurate.